# float or double type depend on size of pointer

Tags: c++

I want to declare a struct where one of my type is either float or double depending on pointer size.

```
#if size of pointer is 4
# define Real float
#else
# define Real double
#endif 
struct mydata {
 //...
 Real speed;
 //... 
};
#undefine Real
```

without using macro?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do this?    Without such an explanation, this question is likely to be regarded as an example of an XY problem.  Such questions rarely attract useful answers, even if they have solutions, since the solutions rarely target the actual problem.   For a discussion of how to avoid constructing XY problems, have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: to get better memory align of my struct.

Comment: there's `alignas(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) (or `conditional_t`) to choose a type based on a compile-time condition:

```
#include <type_traits>

using Real = std::conditional_t<sizeof(void*) == 4, float, double>;
```

If you use C++11 but not C++14, you'd need:

```
using Real = std::conditional<sizeof(void*) == 4, float, double>::type;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `std::conditional`:

```
#include <type_trais>

using Real = std::conditional<sizeof(void*) == 4, float, double>::type;
```